# Are A and Hom(A,Q/Z) isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

If A is a Z-module, does this imply that A and Hom(A,Q/Z) are isomorphic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $A=\mathbf Z$. Are $\mathbf Z$ and $\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z$ isomorphic?

Comment: They are not isomorphic while Z isomorphic to Hom(Z,Z)

Comment: @sam In general, for an abelian group G, G is canonically isomorphic to Hom(Z, G).

Comment: Is there any special property for Hom(-,Q/Z)?

Comment: @sam Yes, many. Read about pontryagin duality, injective modules...

Comment: I know that Q/Z is injective and torsion , and I asked the above question to prove that the map that takes from A to Hom(Hom(A,Q/Z),Q/Z) is one to one.